# Why are colors not working in matplotlib for this example?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Why am I not seeing any red colors for the negative values here?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, -2, 3, -4])
df['positive'] = df[[0]]>0
df[[0]].plot(kind='bar', color=df.positive.map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
```

[image]

I am expecting negative values to be red!

As per our discussion below, this is a bug in the latest version of pandas 0.20.2.

Comment: Can you show the output you are getting and the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Ahmed updated the question

Comment: I have them red

Comment: @tarashypka I do not. Mine is all green.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I believe this might be a bug in the latest version https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16822 Your code produces red and green bars using version (0.20.1)

Comment: @johnchase I am using pandas 0.20.2.

Comment: @johnchase Do you know any ETA on this fix? Has a pull request been submitted?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not involved with the project enough to know what the status is beyond what is already discussed in the issue tracker. Downgrading the version seems like it would be the easiest solution, if that is possible

Comment: @johnchase Everything is possible...

Comment: @MadPhysicist That was just linked above

Comment: @Pii. My bad, will delete. My comments werent updated when I posted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [bug](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16822) as mentioned by @johnchase.

One workaround till it gets resolved :

```
print(''.join(df.positive.map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}).values))    # 'grgr'
df[[0]].plot(kind='bar', color=''.join(df.positive.map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}).values))
```

which outputs

[image]