# df.map not working when coloring plot graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have the following columns on my dataframe, which is basically an index and a column that is either True, False or '-'.

```
print(df.ColorCond)
```

Returns:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rp7G.png)

Before I plot my graph I have this syntax:

```
plotprod = df['Sum_Pond'].plot(kind="bar", title="Produccio Abril 2017", rot=0, figsize=(15,7), yticks=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], color=df.ColorCond.map({True :'g', False : 'r', '-': 'white'}))
```

This will plot the following Graph:

[Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buaWe.png)

imports used:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as matplotlib
```

Upon further testing I switch the order of color map to see if it was simply picking the first option, but it still pinted on the True : 'g', no matter the order.

The code, regarding this part, is almost identical to the one I used in a jupyter environment and worked as expected!

What could it be?

Please let me know if you need any more data.

Comment: Try putting quotations around `True` and `False`. I don't think they are of type bool.

Comment: There is a bug report about this that I saw as an answer yesterday... let me try dig it out. I can't remember if it was pandas or matplotlib but it was on their Github for the latest version. Not finding it easy to pin down.

Comment: @A.Kot not working!

Comment: Solved in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175916/why-are-colors-not-working-in-matplotlib-for-this-example